# Background image in react-admin Login page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, admin-on-rest, react-admin

I want to use a image to be put in as background image of login page in `react-admin` how can I do this ?

P.S: I'm using `TypeScript`

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please include whatever code you've already tried and explain where something isn't working as you expect it to work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Admin` component have a `loginPage` prop. You can pass a custom component in that.

Here is an example, create your LoginPage component:

```
// LoginPage.js
import React from 'react';
import { Login, LoginForm } from 'react-admin';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = ({
    main: { background: '#333' },
    avatar: {
        background: 'url(//cdn.example.com/background.jpg)',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        backgroundSize: 'contain',
        height: 80,
    },
    icon: { display: 'none' },
});

const CustomLoginForm = withStyles({
    button: { background: '#F15922' },
})(LoginForm);

const CustomLoginPage = props => (
    <Login
        loginForm={<CustomLoginForm />}
        {...props}
    />
);

export default withStyles(styles)(CustomLoginPage);
```

And use it in your Admin:

```
// App.js
import { Admin } from 'react-admin';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';

export default const App = () => (
    <Admin
        loginPage={LoginPage}
        {...props}
    >
        {resources}
    </Admin>
);
```

More infos about this prop in the documentation: [`Admin.loginPage`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#loginpage)

Comment: Thanks for the Solution.

Answer (score 4):

For just a background image and nothing else:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#using-a-custom-login-page you only need:

```
import { Admin, Login } from 'react-admin';

const MyLoginPage = () => <Login backgroundImage="/background.jpg" />;

const App = () => (
    <Admin loginPage={MyLoginPage}>
    </Admin>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I find this solution in React Admin's issues

```
import React from 'react';
import { Login, LoginForm } from 'ra-ui-materialui';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = {
    login: {
        main: {
            backgroundImage: 'url(https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?traffic,road)',
        },
        card: {
            padding: '5px 0 15px 0',
        },
    },
    form: {
        button: {
            height: '3em',
        },
    },
};

const MyLoginForm = withStyles(styles.form)(LoginForm);

const MyLogin = (props) => (
    <Login loginForm={<MyLoginForm />} {...props} />
);

export default withStyles(styles.login)(MyLogin);
```

This is link [click here](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/1853)